# Javascript - Pause video when changing to another tab (on the same page)

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

So I have 3 tabs set up pretty much exactly like this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp - but the content under each tab is a different video (HTML). My problem is that after changing tabs, the video/audio from the previous tab continues to play - unless I pause the video prior to switching tabs. I've tried a few of the different solutions I've seen for problems similar to this, but still can't find a solution that works on my page.

Here is the HTML I have -

```
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'BEE')" id="defaultOpen">BEE</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'CRAB')">CRAB</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'CROW')">CROW</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="BEE" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="video">
  <video width="852" height="480" controls>
    <source src="bee.mov" type="video/mp4">
  </video> 
</div>
</div>

<div id="CRAB" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="video">
  <video width="852" height="480" controls>
    <source src="crab.mov" type="video/mp4">
  </video> 
 </div>
</div>

<div id="CROW" class="tabcontent">
 <div class="video">
  <video width="852" height="480" controls>
    <source src="crow.mov" type="video/mp4">
  </video> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Here are some of the different solutions I've tried -
#1 - The main one I keep coming back to - [Pause/stop videos into tabs when I clicked on a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995609/pause-stop-videos-into-tabs-when-i-clicked-on-a-tab)
#2 - [How to pause a video when another video's play button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861861/how-to-pause-a-video-when-another-videos-play-button-is-clicked)
#3 - I've tried to see if there's a way I could switch the space bar to clicking anywhere on this one - https://teamtreehouse.com/community/hi-how-can-i-make-the-video-startstop-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-video-icon-instead-of-targeting-the-play-button

I'm still very new to JS so any help or suggestions are very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to show us the different solutions you have tried in order to expect an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause all videos when one of the tabs is clicked:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    tabcontent[i].querySelector("video").pause();
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent .video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>
```